# jsf validation custom messages

Tags: validation, jsf

I am new to XHTMLs, I require some help regarding validation messages .
 when I tried to validate the user controls on client side, getting the error message in full form like

> createUser:user: Validation Error: Value is required.
>   createUser:firstName: Validation Error: Value is required.

The validation part I am using

```
<h:inputText id="user" value="#{createUser.userName}" required="true">
<f:validateLength minimum="1" maximum="15"></f:validateLength></h:inputText>
<h:message for="user" style="color:red" />
```

Is it possible to display the error message part alone (Value is required) using client side validations alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize error messages in JSF. You can look this page.

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Hi,

I am still getting the default error message.

Comment: Can you show your code, message.properties and your faces-config xml

Comment: Message.properties

javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM=Minimum length of ''{0}'' is required.
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM={1}: Length is greater than allowable maximum of ''{0}''

Comment: hi, sorry i didn't know to place the code in format in this page...

Comment: Ok no problem. In message.properties   you show me Length validator. In this case you should change javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED message like "javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = Value is Required".

Comment: when required="true" this mesage show--> javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED  if you want to validateLength minimum  this message javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM, if you want to lenght maximum  javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM  so also you should change for lenghth validator maximum and minumum like javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM = Length is greater than allowable maximum of {0} and javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM = Length is greater than allowable maximum of ''{0}''.

Comment: Becauuse you change .LengthValidator.MINIMUM , you should change LengthValidator.MAXIMUM for max length

Comment: Hi, I have changed the MAXIMUM validator code . the problem was i was using ':' instead of = javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM={1}: Length is greater than allowable maximum of ''{0}'' later i changed to javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM=Length is greater than allowable maximum of ''{0}'' 
Also required="true" validation was overriding the min/max validations. I removed them.
Thanks a lot for your pateience and help...